# Changing/Adding Toolbar Name in QGIS?

Tags: qgis-plugins, toolbar

I installed the **Customize ToolBars** plugin and created a few custom toolbars. However, I saw they only get a label name instead of the actual toolbar name. I checked customization and also printed all toolbars via Python:

```py
from PyQt4.QtGui import QToolBar

for x in iface.mainWindow().findChildren(QToolBar): 
    if x:
        print x.objectName()
```

This results in the following outputs. The plugins I want to find names for are showing up blank or empty.

Is there a way to just add some name to these unnamed toolbars?

[image: output]

Answer (score 1):

When loading the stored custom toolbars, the plugin doesn't give them names, as far as I can tell it rather works with window titles. So you'd have to do it by yourself - it probably won't do no harm to the plugin.

What you have to do is to change function `MyToolBars(self)` in `CustomToolbar.py` by searching for line:

```py
self.bar = self.iface.mainWindow().addToolBar(item.text(0))
```

and adding another line:

```py
self.bar.setObjectName(item.text(0))
```

Maybe the author would agree to add it to his plugin, if you ask him(?)

Comment: Probably fix it in a Qgis 3 version plugin.